# CSS transform vs position

Tags: css, performance, layout

Can some please explain to me the difference in transitioning the positional `left` or `right` properties or the `-transform: translateX(n)`, as the both seem to achieve the same thing yet can be applied independently. I understand about the possibility of hardware acceleration but that's dependent on implementation.

```
// psuedo code;

#box {
    -transition-property: all;
    -transition-duration: 1s;
}

// javascript

box.style.transform = "translateX(200px)";
vs
box.style.left = "200px";
```

What's the advantage of one over the other?
Thanks,

p

Comment: There is good article: [Why Moving Elements With Translate() Is Better Than Pos:abs Top/left](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/why-moving-elements-with-translate-is-better-than-posabs-topleft/)

Answer (score 94):

The drawing order of rendering layers is:

- layout layer
- paint layer
- compositor layer

A redraw in a layer will trigger redraw in subsequent layers.

Changing `left` or `margin` will trigger a redraw in **layout layer** (which, in turn, will trigger redraws in the other two layers) for the animated element **and for subsequent elements in DOM**.

Changing `transform` will trigger a redraw in **compositor layer** *only for the animated element* (subsequent elements in DOM **will not** be redrawn).

The difference in performance (hence in frames per second or, in simple terms, in animation smoothness) is tremendous. Using the first technique will often result in jittery animations even on good machines (when the processor is busy), while the second will likely run smoothly even on systems with limited resources.

Another advantage of using `transform`s is compositor redraws are heavily optimized (animations to multiple elements result in one redraw for all), while changing layout layer will trigger a redraw after each change of each element.

For a more detailed explanation on rendering techniques and rendering performance I recommend Google's [Web Fundamentals](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/rendering/).

Answer (score 17):

Position is dependant on what the `position` is set to, `transform` works from the element itself. So you *could* see `transform` as being identical to `position:relative;`.

However, you can still use `transform` on an absolutely positioned element (to position it relatively without needing an additional element or resorting to margins), as well as `transform` being CSS3 so if you can use `position` instead you should.

Comment: I'm not really sure I understand what your saying. Let me clarify my position. It doesn't really matter what position is set to, the above example provides 2 different ways of do the same thing. This is surely something the CSS spec should avoid.

Answer (score 10):

`top` and `left` CSS properties work only on elements positioned `relative`, `absolute` or `fixed`. Also, `top` and `left` properties rely on the parent's position (relative it, absolute or static). Translations are not affected by that settings.

---

Translation transformations are "identical" to applying `top` and `left` when element has `position: relative`. In any other case they aren't the same operations.

Comment: How is this any different than using a margin

Comment: Also worth noting that the performance when transitioning a translate value is far smoother than using a positional or margin value.

Comment: Performance is dependent upon browser implementation. I more interested in the philosophical reasons for what get included in the spec.

Comment: @WillDen Margin affects the layout where transforms don't.

Comment: Performance test on various browsers: http://jsperf.com/translate3d-vs-xy/4 (top/left) is the fastest.

Comment: @Kus That test is absolutely useless. It is measuring the speed at which the code evaluates, it doesn't take into account browser rendering speed (repaints, etc.).

Answer (score 7):

As mention above:
`position:relative` and `translate` can achieve the same effect in a different way

`position:relative` happen in the layout phase which means it can **interact** with other elements in terms of layout

while `translate` happens when all the layout process complete, further it even already painted, what is remaining is a matter where to put the element, so it has no **interaction** with the existing layout

consider the following example which will present an obvious visual difference by using the two methods

```
    .container {
        width: 300px;
        height: 300px;
        overflow: scroll;
        background: red;
    }

    .child {
        width: 280px;
        height: 280px;
        background: green;
    }
    <div class="container">
        <div class="child"></div>
    </div>
```

By setting `position:relative;top:100px` to the child element, the container has no enough space to hold the child, and because of the fact that `overflow` is set as `scroll`, the scroll bar will present

On the other hand, By setting `transform:translateY(100px)`, it has **nothing to do with the layout**, so the scrollbar will not present

Like the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visuren.html#block-formatting) said:

> However, if relative positioning causes an 'overflow:auto' or
> 'overflow:scroll' box to have overflow, the UA must allow the user to
> access this content (at its offset position), which, through the
> creation of scrollbars, may affect layout

To conclude, `position` is involved in layout, while `transform` not, which means `transform` can have better performance.

**prefer `transform` to `position` when the layout is not your concern**

Comment: Either your answer isn't quite accurate, this has recently changed, or I'm doing something wrong. In Chrome Version 103.0.5060.134, I'm getting scroll bars being added in with both position relative and translateY. I created a fiddle to show: https://jsfiddle.net/dillydadally/r95L0tjw/