# CSS move element by position or by transform?

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions

Show I use absolute position or transform to move a `<div>` around the page?

I seem to recall reading that moving objects using position such as:

```
dialog.style.bottom = "100px";
```

is slower and it is preferable to use transform to move the object instead:

```
dialog.style.transform = "translateY(100px);
```

However as I also have a CSS transition in place:

```
transition: 2s
```

does that make any difference, is transform still preferred over position or are they both the same now?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7108941/css-transform-vs-position transform vs position

Comment: The actual question seems to have got a bit lost in the various replies.  The crux of it is whether position with a transition is any different to a transform?

I understand the differences between a straight position vs transform but what about a position with transition?

Answer (score 8):

If you want it animated, move it using `transform`:

```js
dialog.style.transform = "translateY(100px)";
```

```css
#dialog {transform: translateY(50px); transition: all 2s;}
```

```html
<div id="dialog">Hello</div>
```

Also read [**Why Moving Elements With Translate() Is Better Than Pos:abs Top/left**](https://www.paulirish.com/2012/why-moving-elements-with-translate-is-better-than-posabs-topleft/).

Comment: Yes, but why? Should have explained that, anyway, here it is: https://www.paulirish.com/2012/why-moving-elements-with-translate-is-better-than-posabs-topleft/

Answer (score 1):

> "Better", v1
>
> My first thought on what "better" meant in this context is which one
>   is more appropriate to use under different circumstances. Which leads
>   me to say: "don't confuse positioning with design-y motion."
>
> Case in point. You have a button. You want to apply an effect to that
>   button so that in it's :active state it nudges down 2 pixels to mimic
>   a "pushed" effect. That is a design-y motion that should be done with
>   translate(). You could do it with top or bottom and relative
>   positioning, but then you are confusing the concepts of positioning
>   and design-y motion.
>
> Let's say somewhere else in the app you absolutely position a button
>   (perfectly legit). Now when that top: 2px; gets applied to the button
>   in it's :active state, that button will likely go zooming off
>   someplace you didn't expect, possibly making the button unclickable.
>
> Using translate() will always "nudge" the element from it's current
>   position which is perfect for an effect like this, or really any
>   design-specific motion."[Chris Coyier](https://css-tricks.com/author/chriscoyier/) at [A Tale of Animation Performance](https://css-tricks.com/tale-of-animation-performance/)

Read this article please, it will provide you with all what you want to know about that topic.
https://www.paulirish.com/2012/why-moving-elements-with-translate-is-better-than-posabs-topleft/

Comment: I get the feeling it seems to be a matter of opinion then, no definitive answer to the basic question.