# Which of these css snippets is more performant and why?

Tags: css

I recently got asked which of these snippets was more performant in a code test for a job. Which is correct and why?

```css
/* Option 1 */
.nav {
  left: -250px;
  transition: left 300ms linear;
}

.nav--open {
  left: 0px;
  transition: left 300ms linear;
}

/* Option 2 */
.nav {
  transform: translateX(-250px);
  transition: transform 300ms linear;
}

.nav--open {
  transform: none;
  transition: transform 300ms linear;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS transform vs position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7108941/css-transform-vs-position)

Comment: Check out https://csstriggers.com/

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/performance-tools/

Answer (score 1):

It has to do with frame rates. Animating the `left` property triggers layout which might lead to skipped frames. Transforms are better to animate because they do not trigger layout or paints and can be hardware accelerated.

To achieve a silky smooth 60fps in your CSS animations, you want to limit, as much as you can, your animations to the properties `opacity`, `translate`, `rotate` and `scale`. You should always look to avoid animating properties that will trigger layout or paints, both of which are expensive and may lead to skipped frames.

Have a look at this article by Paul Lewis and Paul Irish, written in 2013 but relevant to date - https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/high-performance-animations/